# how to prove uniform convergence of truncated product $\cos_n(z)$ to $\cos(z)$ in the compact set $|\Re(z)|<a,|\Im(z)|<b$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

The function $\cos(x)$ can be expressed as an infinite product in terms of its zeros
$$\cos(z)=\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{((2k+1)\pi/2)^2}\right)\tag{1}$$

Let us define

$$\cos_n(x)=\prod_{k=0}^{n}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{((2k+1)\pi/2)^2}\right)\tag{2}$$

How to prove that $\cos_n(z)$ uniformly converges to $\cos(z)$ in the compact set $\{|\mathrm{Re}(z)|<a,|\mathrm{Im}(z)|<b\}$?

Comment: no. I am not Mike Nuccio.

Comment: that it converges uniformly ? or uniformly to $\cos(z)$ ? for the latter I prove first the formula for $cotan(\pi z)$ by substracting all its poles at $z = k$ of order $1$ and residue $1/ \pi$, and proving it is a bounded entire function with the Liouville theorem. and that it converges uniformly (to the infinite product in (1) ) is obvious by looking at the logarithm and using $|\log(1+z) - z| < 2 z^2$ when $|z| \to 0$ small enough

Comment: @user1952009. Uniformly to $\cos(z)$ of course. Thanks for the hint. Could you write the complete answer? I am not math major and I still can not figure out how to complete the proof based on your hint. Best

Comment: do you know the Liouville theorem ? and that $cotan(z)$ meromorphic $\implies$ after substracting its poles (which are of order $1$) it becomes holomorphic ? all you have to do then is proving that the obtained entire function is bounded

Comment: note that $\frac{\cos(z)}{\sin(z)}$ is itself bounded on $\mathbb{C} \setminus A$ where $A$ is the set of $\epsilon$ balls around $k \pi, k\in \mathbb{Z}$, note that $h(z) =\frac{1}{z} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z-\pi k} +\frac{1}{z+\pi k}$ is also bounded on $\mathbb{C} \setminus A$, hence all you have to prove is that $\frac{\cos(z)}{\sin(z)}- h(z)$ is bounded on $A$, which is obvious. overall you get $ \frac{\cos(z)}{\sin(z)}- h(z) = C$ for some constant $C$ and $C=0$ by letting $Im(z) \to \infty$

Comment: I am phys major and I do not know Liouville theorem. I will definitely look it up. Taking logarithm rings bell to me. I did one such uniform convergence proof related from truncated sum of $\cos(x)$ to $]cos(x)$.

Comment: @user1952009. Please provide me with a reference. I need to do a similar proof for a different function and I just need a reference in my manuscript. Best

Comment: Are you sure this converges uniformly? If I'm not mistaken, every $\cos_n$ is an unbounded function on $\Bbb R$ (since it's a nonconstant polynomial), and $\cos$ is bounded on $\operatorname{Im}(z)<1$, so uniform convergence is impossible.

Comment: @Wojowu: thanks for the comment!. I encountered this problem in my first trial. Does changing the strip $\mathrm{Im}(z)<1$ to rectangle $\{\mathrm{Im}(z)<1,\mathrm{Re}(z)<n\}$ or something like that help?

Comment: Yes, that should make it work.

Comment: @Wojowu : $\cos(z)$ is bounded on $|Im(z)| < C$ and for the $\cos_n(z)$ you should look at their logarithms.

Comment: @user1952009 It's not true that uniform convergence of logarithms implies uniform convergence of the functions, if this is what you're implying.

Comment: @Wojowu  but yes, you are right, it converges uniformly on every compacts, the $\cos_n(z)$ are polynomials hence they can't be bounded when $|z| \to \infty$ sorry, they don't converge uniformly in the whole strip. (and from the logarithm,  we can see if it converges uniformly, by looking carefully at where are the zeros, but I agree it is not adapted so well here)

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the helpful discussion. Now I start to understand the meaning of "compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$" that appeared often in the proof of uniform convergence.